# How can I ringfence an EXE to know what system resources it is accessing?

Tags: debuggers

I do not want to debug the code within the program, I simply want to know what external resources it accesses - files, connections, registry, etc...  Is there an easy way to do this in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You can use utilities from [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default) package, such as [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Comment: Doesn't that only list what resources it currently has opened?  I'm looking for a history of what it touched/opened in detail as it started/ran/closed.

Comment: No, it logs access to system resources.

Comment: Or ApiMonitor for that matter :)

Comment: @dominik-antal : ApiMonitor search turns up a few things.  Can you be specific?

w-s : Processmonitor is not being specific.  It only lists full directories and key branchs the program accesses, not specific keys or files.  ...and doesn't provide a timestamp of first/last access.  Saying "HKCU" in the lower panel isn't useful.

Comment: Are you running process monitor as administrator ?

Comment: Yes.  I notice that some entries in the lower panel are more specific so is it possible the application is requesting the entire registry tree (all HKLU) and all files under a directory?

Comment: Would you post the application log somewhere? It is a bit hard to solve problems blindly.